# UITableViewCell behaves differently in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have done a `UITableViewCell` programmatically and it worked just fine with iOS 10. But after updating with iOS 11 and XCode 9, it behaves differently. The layout looks scrambled as below.

[image]

But if I tap on the cell then it rearranges and looks fine as below.

[image]

Here the code for `UITableViewCell`

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class AboutCell: UITableViewCell {

    let roleLabel : UILabel = {
        var tablelabel = UILabel()
        tablelabel.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir Next Medium", size: 22)
        tablelabel.textAlignment = .center
        tablelabel.clipsToBounds = true
        tablelabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tablelabel
    }()
    let nameLabel : UILabel = {
        let tablelabel = UILabel()
        tablelabel.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir Next Medium", size: 16)
        tablelabel.textAlignment = .center
        tablelabel.clipsToBounds = true
        tablelabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tablelabel
    }()
    let webUrlLabel : UILabel = {
        let tablelabel = UILabel()
        tablelabel.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir Next Medium", size: 16)
        tablelabel.textAlignment = .center
        tablelabel.clipsToBounds = true
        tablelabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tablelabel
    }()


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupViews()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        roleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: self.contentView.bounds.size.width-20, height: 25)
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: roleLabel.frame.origin.y+25, width: self.bounds.size.width-20, height: 25)
        webUrlLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: nameLabel.frame.origin.y+25, width: self.bounds.size.width-20, height: 25)

    }

    func setupViews(){
        contentView.addSubview(roleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(webUrlLabel)
    }

    func setValuesForCell(contributor : Contributors){
        roleLabel.text = contributor.contributorRole
        nameLabel.text = contributor.contributorName
        webUrlLabel.text = contributor.contributorWeb
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

and the extension I wrote for TableView delegate and datasource

```
extension AboutController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contributorList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : AboutCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellid, for: indexPath) as! AboutCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
        let contributor : Contributors = contributorList[indexPath.row]
        cell.setValuesForCell(contributor: contributor)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }
}
```

and the ViewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        tableView.register(AboutCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellid)

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.right.bottom.left.equalToSuperview()
        }

        let mayu = Contributors(contibutorRole: "Developer", contributorName: "J Mayooresan", contributorWeb: "http://jaymayu.com")
        let janie = Contributors(contibutorRole: "Voice Artist", contributorName: "M Jananie", contributorWeb: "http://jaymayu.com")
        let arjun = Contributors(contibutorRole: "Aathichudi Content", contributorName: "Arjunkumar", contributorWeb: "http://laymansite.com")
        let artist = Contributors(contibutorRole: "Auvaiyar Art", contributorName: "Alvin", contributorWeb: "https://www.fiverr.com/alvincadiz18")

        contributorList = [mayu, arjun, janie, artist]

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

Comment: just reload your table when you get your data

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes I did that already but it didn't help.

Comment: @ReshanKumarasingam: Where have you set the cell height?

Comment: @PuneetSharma I did it in ViewDidLoad. I updated the question accordingly. Please check.

Comment: If you're using autolayout for your tableView, don't you need to also set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`? Additionally, if the cells aren't using autolayout (you're laying out your views manually) then you should not touch `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

Comment: @ajfigueroa Wow! you are correct. It solved the issue. Can you write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ReshanKumarasingam Wait, SnapKit should set this to `false` for you already. What change fixed the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Since you're laying out your tableView using autolayout, you also need to ensure `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false`.</s>

SnapKit should be setting the tableView's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for you already.

Since you're laying out the cells manually (using frames in layoutSubviews). Setting the cells subview's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` is likely not needed.

See Apple Docs here for [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)

Comment: @ReshanKumarasingam Anbu.Karthik is correct! SnapKit sets it to false for you already. What change did you make to fix this?

Comment: i dont say your answer is wrong, may be it fixed the probelm, are you sure its the exact issue for affect the frame

Comment: @ReshanKumarasingam - ensure once your code will support for iphone-X also